# How can a React parent component with arbitrarily many children update a selected child by its string id without using useRef?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, web-architecture, react-sortable-hoc

I have a React Hook component named List for example with an arbitrary number of children called Entry (adding or removing is possible). If data for an Entry changes, how can I update it without re-rendering the parent which will re-render all its siblings which may be huge. I would like to avoid useRef and useImperativeHandle, first because my codes becomes more complex and using react-sortable-hoc makes it impossible to use them.

Answer (score 0):

No child component can re-render if its parent doesn't. You should instead prevent re-render for your `Entry` component by using `React.memo` or `shouldComponentUpdate`, so that children that haven't changed won't be re-rendered.